# CountIf statement excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I want to be able to check if data in one cell in column a = x and then if so count the data in adjacent cell in column b.

To explain in more detail, I am creating a statistics chart where commissioners need to be able to be able to compare data for region 1 to region 2 and region 3.

So column A will contain region keys such as 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 then in column B will be ages. So if column A contains a 1 collect data in cell adjacent to the cell it is counting.

I hope this makes sense.

So I want the formula to only count the cells that adjacent cells contain district 1 for example

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>  
    
  </tr>
  
 <tr>
    <td>District 1</td>
    <td>12</td>  
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>District 2</td>
    <td>12</td>  
    
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>District 1</td>
    <td>12</td>  
    
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>District 2</td>
    <td>12</td>  
    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what's wrong with using `COUNTIF()`?

Comment: I am not sure if I can use count if for COUNTIF(cell a1="1", count cell b1) for example

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation of your data. Try presenting example data in a table in your question.

Comment: does this make sense?

Comment: Not really what I meant about putting it in a table but nicely done anyway. What output did you want? Just `Count of district 1 = 2` and `Count of district 2 = 2`?

Comment: haha only way I could think of doing it. 

what I want is for the formula to count the total number of 12 year olds that live in district 1 for example.

Comment: on a larger scale, it will count the number of all ages and put them in a group depending on the district they are from. this is going to be the same for ethnicity, disability etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [`COUNTIFS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed) to add extra criteria to when to count something.

Using the following data:

```
Region  Age
2       12
2       16
2       41
1       62
3       26
3       50
2       12
1       65
3       64
```

Where Region = B1 we can use `=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,2,B2:B10,12)` to count the instances where Region = 2 and where Age = 12. This returns 2.

Obviously we can expand this out to all manner of criteria or keep adding extra criteria. Having data that looks like:

```
Region  Age Ethnicity
2       12  Black
2       16  Caucasian
2       41  Asian
1       62  Black
3       26  Caucasian
3       50  Asian
2       12  Caucasian
1       65  Caucasian
3       64  Asian
```

We can now count Asian people equal to or over the age of 50 in region 3 with `=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,3,B2:B10,">=50",C2:C10,"Asian")`

And if you want to bucket people using upper and lower bounds it's simply a case of creating the bound in separate ranges and criteria pairs. For instance to find all people in region 2 aged between 10 and 20 (not inclusive on the upper bound) we would use `=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,2,B2:B10,">=10",B2:B10,"<20")`

Comment: Great example and explanation.

Comment: So with a little editing I guess this could work =COUNTIFS(B2:B10,2,C2:C10,10>20<)

Comment: For people between 10 and 20 and in region 2? For that you'd use `=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,2,B2:B10,">=10",B2:B10,"<20")` This would count people aged 10 to 19 in region 2. Notice how I put the lower bound in one range and criteria pair and the upper bound in another range and criteria pair.

Comment: You Sir, are an absolute legend! how do you know this !